# CoffeeScript Mongodb variable passing

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript

```
db.collection('database_name')
  .find( { 'active':true, 'iOS':true} )
  .toArray (err, dbDocs) ->
```

returns me a result set .

However,

```
deviceName = 'iOS'
db.collection('database_name')
  .find( { 'active':true, deviceName:true} )
  .toArray (err, dbDocs) ->
```

doesnt work.

`deviceName` is a coffeescript string variable initialized to iOS `deviceName = 'iOS'`

How do I pass the variable `deviceName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use object literals if your field names are dynamic, you have to build the query object programmatically:

```
query = { active: true };
query[deviceName] = true if something;

db.collection('database_name').find( query ).toArray (err, dbDocs) ->
```

Comment: { $and: [ { 'active':true }, {'platform': { $in : ['Android'] } } ] } 
If I have to build a query like above, and ['Android'] is a dynamic variable. How to go about it ?

Comment: That's okay. Only dynamic field names are "tricky", for values you can use variables. `{ platform: { $in : anArrayVariable }}`

Comment: db.collection('database_name').find( {$and: [ { active:true }, { platform: { $in : deviceName } } ] }).toArray (err, dbDocs) 

deviceName is an array for me and it will be populated at runtime.